# Performance/Memory impact using multiple .NET runtime in one solution

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Are there going to be any impacts on performance or memory consumption if the solution I work on (200ish csprojects) is completely built for one .NET CLR version (4.5), but extensively uses 3rd party libraries built for older .NET CLR (2.0/1.1) - in my case Common.Logging 1.2?

Studying various materials (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx) indicate most likely there will be an increase in memory consumption due to Side-by-Side, but it's not clear whether there will be any performance hit due to SxS compared to taking effort and rebuilding all referenced 3rd party libraries for same .NET CLR.

Let's say my .NET4.5 solution extensively uses common.logging (.NET2.0/1.1). If I take an effort and rebuild (+update sources if necessary) this common.logging to .NET4.5, does my solution speed up (and if so, is it enough to make the effort worth it)?

edit (clarification):
The solution produces stand-alone application (no IIS/ASP.NET) executable.

Comment: Is too difficult to evaluate the impact of the suggested work. Use 4.5 instead of 2.0 maybe can speedup, but a lot of improvment can be performed modifying the old code with new/rewited APIs of .NET4.5. At the end what I can say is, probably **can** speed it up

Comment: The entry point application determine the runtime used. Everything else will be loaded in that runtime given it is version compatible.

Comment: Are you sure you actually running 2 runtimes? (it is generally hard to achieve with strictly managed code, so there is a good chance that you are not)...

Comment: The entry point (C# .NET executable) is built for .NET4.5. Alas it is using older .NET libraries. From my understanding of .NET runtime compatibility, since .NET4.0, it is actually capable loading as many runtimes as needed within one process.

Comment: Multiple runtimes can be run side by side yes, but not from a managed .net executable entry point.  It will use unification as described below and every dll targetting previous versions of the framework will be run on the newer CLR (so .net 2.0 dll's run on the 4.5 framework).  Running side by side CLR's is only possible if you build a bootstrapper in C++ and leverage the CLR hosting apis or a similar approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumption**: Your application is one primary application which loads several assemblies which are targetting different framework versions.

While your assemblies are targeting different .NET framework versions, they will all use the one loaded by your application due to [Assembly Unification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db7849ey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is the default behavior, which means that it wont load extra runtimes. This behavior can be overridden, also described on MSDN, which means that you have to specify if you want side-by-side execution using extra runtimes.

**Answer:** Your solution will not speed up by rebuilding your older projects in .NET 4.5 since unification already executes those assemblies in .NET 4.5.

From the linked page.

> In the following illustration, the application MyApp uses two components, Comp A and Comp B. MyApp and Comp A were built with runtime version 1.0, so they contain static references to runtime version 1.0. Component Comp B contains a static reference to a .NET Framework assembly that shipped with runtime version 1.1, but because of unification, is redirected to run using the .NET Framework assembly that shipped with runtime version 1.0.
>   [image: Image describing assembly unification]

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible for 1 process to use multiple versions of the CLR with managed executables targetting a specific version of the framework.  This is why a project built on say .Net 2.0 can't reference a dll built on .Net 4.5.  However a project built on 4.5 can reference a dll built on 2.0 because the CLR's are backwards compatible with each other.

In the event of a process, say a Windows Forms App built on .Net 4.5 referencing a .net 2.0 Depedency the Dependency will use the 4.5 Framework, stepping up.

Now if we are talking IIS applications, it would be possible to have two web apps in 1 solution built against two different .net versions and both use those version, but only if each web app is given it's own application pool either via 2 separate iis sites, or 1 IIS site with two separate sub applications with each application using a different Application Pool.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "It's impossible for 1 process to use multiple versions of the CLR" that is not correct. It is correct for managed executables (which is possibly what you ment), but it is possible when you write your own (native) executable to host multible different versions of the CLR.

Comment: Based on the lack of a c or c++ tag, I would assume the OP isn't managing a native process and using the CLR hosting apis.

Comment: I agree. I just think your introductory sentence needs a little refinement, not being technically correct. But it is your choice of wording.

Comment: According to the article linked in the question, that is not entirely true (or at least that's how I understood it) - quote "As part of our new approach of having multiple runtimes in a process, we have deprecated the old, single-runtime-aware hosting APIs and added a new set of hosting APIs designed to help you manage a multi-runtime environment."